# JQuery mobile text field not loosing focus

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am new to JQuery mobile and Cordova.I created a simple Cordova application with JQuery mobile having a form with a simple text-field and a radio input.However I noticed a problem when the application was run as I typed in some text and click on the radio button ,I notices the focus is still on the text input.If JQuery mobile was not used the focus will be out from the text input.I know that JQuery mobile adds some default styles to these form elements.I don't want the focus to be in text-field when I choose to select a radio button.Please help me on this.My code for the HTML page is given below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>            
            <form>
                <label for="text-basic">Text input:</label>
                <input type="text" name="text-basic" id="text-basic" value="">               
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>Radio buttons, vertical controlgroup:</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked">
                    <label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2">
                    <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3">
                    <label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4">
                    <label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The screenshot of Mobile View is attached below.

[image]

Here in the above image you can see the Android keyboard not closing even If I select an element from radio button list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("input:radio").addEventListener('touchstart',function(e) {
     $('input[type=text], textarea').focusout();
});
```

it manual removes focus from the textarea or textinput when an input type radio is touched .

or try this

```
$("input:radio").addEventListener('touchstart',function(e) {
     $(':focus').blur();
});
```